# CSS Class Nth Child selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, css-selectors

Here is my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WajLA/15/)

i don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I found that in this line:

```
<label>City<font color="red">*</font>: <input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></label><br/>
```

If you remove:

```
</label><br/>
```

It, for some reason, works. I have no idea why. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention what works.  I want the style of the first and second submit buttons to be different. So for the submit button on the 2nd form, i used the nth-child selector but for some reason it is not applying the correct style changes to the 2nd submit button. Like i said, it works if you remove the above piece for some reason.

Comment: You might want to explain *what you are trying to do*. "It doesn't work" is not an accurate description of what's going wrong either.

Comment: THE FONT TAG?! I think humanities hope just died. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: Which doctype are you using? `font` was deprecated in HTML4. [src](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_font.htm)

Comment: I don't see an `:nth-child()` selector. I only see an `:nth-of-type()` selector, which works differently.

Comment: Make sure all tags are closed. If you delete a closing tag and it works, it might be because there is an unclosed open tag somewhere, or an extra closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give the buttons different classes as it makes your life easier..
Use simple selectors first.. If that does not work then go for others..

Next do not use font tag.. Replace that with a span and give it a error class that has red font..

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    padding:4px 7px;
    background:#CC0000;
    border:0px;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    border-bottom: 1px double #660000;
    border-top: 1px double #660000;
    border-left:1px double #FF0033;
    border-right:1px double #FF0033;
}

.button1
{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    color: #FFF;
    left:0px;
    width:100px;
}

.button2
{
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    color: #00F;
    left:50px;
    width:150px;

}

.error
{
    color: red;
}
```

I placed all the common attributes into one class.. Then button 1 and button2 will have the specific properties for the button..
This makes your code lot cleaner as you do not have any repetitive styles in your document.
​
Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WajLA/34/)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of things wrong, but importantly:

> The label element may contain at most one input, button, select,
>   textarea, or keygen descendant.

You have a label that contains two inputs (First name + last name).

You shouldn't use the font tag either, there's CSS for a reason.

The nth-child issue:

> This pseudo-class matches elements on the basis of their positions within a parent element’s list of child elements.

Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Use different classes or IDs, simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

CSS CODE : `div.box .button:nth-of-type(2)`

There is no element div.box .button:nth-of-type(2) it is `div.box .button:nth-of-type(1)` . For more reference please visit the below link  http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/ .